# Swap items in comma separated list

Tags: vim

Frequently, e.g. when I write Latex code, I come across the task to rearrange items of a list that are separated by commas. This is quickly done if both items are not at the at the beginning or the end of the list. But if they are at the margins, one has to take extra care of the separating comma.

As an example consider

```
\cite{GirR84, Tar00, Tem77}.
```

Is there a smart way in vim to put, e.g., the last item to the front or to the middle position?

Comment: say there is a line `\foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` what do you want to do? by pressing what kind of key? or by command? like Swap(8,3) to get 1,2,8,4,5,6,7,3 ?

Comment: Can be less specific. Like moving the cursor to an item, cut it, move to a different item, and paste before or after...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the following mappings in `.vimrc`, I think I have them from [this tip on wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines):

```
nnoremap <silent> gl "_yiw:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o>/\w\+\_W\+<CR><c-l>
nnoremap <silent> gh "_yiw?\w\+\_W\+\%#<CR>:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o><c-l>
```

`gh` will swap word under the cursor to the left and `gl` to the right.

Comment: Thanks, gl obviously swaps two subsequent items . What is gh supposed to do? Haven't got it working..

Comment: sorry, not if I [vim 7.3, GUI-Version] use it on \cite{bla00,Tr05,blaba,HinPUU09}

Comment: @Jan: I've changed the mappings to more portable versions, try it now.

Comment: Yes, now it works fine. Except from ` s/\(\%#[[:alnum:]_]\+\)\(\_W\+\)\([[:alnum:]_]\+\)/\3\2 ` appearing in the command line and waiting for input after using gh ...(?)

Comment: @Jan: there must be some interference with other items in your vimrc. These mappings work when I use a vimrc that only contains these mappings and `set nocompatible`.

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Everything's fine now. For gh I still had set your previous version of the mapping.

Answer (score 13):

I actually made a plugin to deal with a similar situation called [argumentative.vim](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative). (Sorry for the plug.)

Argumentative.vim provides the following mappings:

- `[,` and `],` motions which will go to the previous or next argument
- `<,` and `>,` to shift an argument left or right
- `i,` and `a,` argument text objects. e.g. `da,`, `ci,` or `yi,`

So with this plugin you move to the argument in question and then do a `<,` or `>,` as many times as needed. It can also take a count e.g. `2>,`.

If you have Tim Pope's excellent [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) plugin installed `<,` and `>,` become repeatable with the `.` command.

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting way of swapping arbitrary things from the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines):

```
:vnoremap <C-X> <Esc>`.``gvP``P
```

Comment: I'm right now using this and it works well. Can anybody explain the commands used?

Comment: This is general, simple and always works (unlike the plugins). How it works: `<Esc>` go to normal mode, `<tick>.` jump to previous change (deleted text), `<tick><tick>` jump to previous position (so that the "previous" jump is now the deleted text position), `gv` select the previous selection, `P` replace it with previous deletion, `<tick><tick>` jump to deleted position, `P` paste the text that got replaced.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the vim plugin [vim-swap](https://github.com/machakann/vim-swap), quite powerful and useful!